# Validate comma separated numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to check if a string has this pattern: `1,2,10,11`.

The rules are:

- It may be a sequence like: `1` or `1,2` or `1,2,n+1`. Many numbers user wants;
- The number must be followed by a *comma* but can't ends with it, like: `1,`;
- The number can have 1 or 2 digits;
- No other character but number and comma, no space or whatever;
- No need to check numbers sequence, this is not the point.

What I have tried is:

- `(\d{1,2})(,)`: This code checks for a `1,` sentence and returns `true` no metters what is on the rest of the string, like `1,afasfs`;
- I've tried look ahead: `(\d{1,2})(?=(,))` but it accepts the above case too;
- The both cases above I can't apply `^` and `$` because it fails on right scenarios like: `1,2,3`.

What I don't know is how to test the entire string. All my tests only checks a part of it(e.g `1,`) not the entire string.

Note: I'm using JavaScript `test()` function. Don't know if is the right one, but I believe that it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/^(\d{1,2},)*\d{1,2}$/
```

### Details:

```
^           - Line start
\d{1,2}     - 1 or 2 digit number
\d{1,2},    - 1 or 2 digit number followed by a comma
(\d{1,2},)* - 0 or more of 1/2 digit number followed by a comma character
\d{1,2}     - 1 or 2 digit number
$           - Line end
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Hey, nice one!! If isn't ask too much, could you please add a little explanation?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Explanation added in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

per OP

> The number must be followed by a comma

so a little modification to anubhava's pattern`/^(\d{1,2},)+\d{1,2}$/` otherwise it will validate single or double digits only like `1` or `10`

Comment: Thank for the answer, but note that on the rules i said: It may be a sequence like: `1`. So it have to validade single numbers to. Thank you anyway.